# Laravel PHP Artisan not working after maintenance mode down enabled

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

When I wanted to deploy a couple of files to live server, I made `php artisan down` and uploaded the files to the live server. On console when I wanted to make the site alive made `php artisan up` but artisan is not responding. I tried other basic commands like `php artisan list` but nothing is going on. I tried `composer dump-autoload`. The commmand worked fine and I got "Generating autoload files" which worked fine I guess. But php artisan commands are still not working. I have googled it but nothing is similar to this situation. Because I have been using php artisan commands earlier but now suddenly not working.

I also tried composer update and I got this error about artisan:

> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like there might be a syntax error in one of the files you uploaded so when that file is autoloaded, it's breaking the app.

Comment: It is working on local server finely. I also deleted "down" file manually in storage/framework but no chance. I still get blank empty screen on my website

Comment: Did you check the laravel.log file?  There might be a hint there.  Does the server have the same php version as the one you are using to develop on?

Comment: Yes I have also checked the log file but there is no log at all (I keep daily log)

Comment: `It is working on local server finely` do you have the same error reporting on local and on the server?

Comment: no it was working in homestead but not on live server.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I had to make a way around which is to creat new laravel project and deploy the project files into new one. It is working now. But could not solve the problem sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Just Manually delete down folder under storage folder
 ie. storage/framework/down